# How to store packages on a separate drive to save disk space in Linux Mint?

Tags: package-management, disk-usage, linux-mint

I'm running Linux Mint 9 from an 8G USB stick and it's nearly full with installed packages. How can I move some (but not all) packages to my internal drive?

Comment: Have you tried to clean up apt's package cache? /var/cache/apt caches the deb-files for the packages you install, and it can get quite big. (On this machine it is 2.7GB).

Comment: To simply do what @Egil suggests, run `apt-get clean`

Comment: This question is unclear. What are you trying to do, exactly? Move your root installation, setup a local apt repository, or just clean out cached packages?

Comment: sorry. I was having trouble writing comments when this question was in the askubuntu forum. Thank you Egil, I will definitely do that. That will help. The reason this question is vague is because I do not know how to ask it. I want my applications to all reside on a separate drive.

Comment: @Joshua: If you want anyone to be notified of your mail, then stick a @user in front. If you want part of your system moved to another drive, you'll have to be a little more specific about what you are trying to do. This is usually straightforward except for the boot process.

Comment: @faheem, thanks. I will remember that. I have been very successful booting linux mint 9 from my usb stick with persistency. Now that I have been installing tons of packages and the drive is getting full I want to move my graphic packages like gimp and open office etc to my computers internal drive. I should be able to just move them and create a symbolic link right? but I don't know where to find them and how to do that. I'm not sure how applications work in the linux world yet.

Comment: @Joshua: I suggest you just reinstall on your hard disk. Running a system off a USB stick is unorthodox and has no upside that I am aware of. If you want you could just move past of the system there, say `/usr`, but I think there is not much point to that.

Comment: @faheem, im more kind of doing this as a learning experience. Windows and Mac allow you to put installed software anywhere you want. When my system folder gets too full I keep my apps on a second drive. Is this not possible in linux or do you just not know?

Comment: @Joshua: You can certainly spread your system across multiple devices if you want, but it is not usually done for a combination of internal and external devices.

Comment: it's too localised, for me

Answer (score 2):

If you have another disk mounted at `/mnt/another_disk`, you can do this:

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/another_disk/apt-cache
sudo mv /var/cache/apt/archives/* /mnt/another_disk/apt-cache
sudo rmdir /var/cache/apt/archives
sudo ln -s /mnt/another_disk/apt-cache /var/cache/apt/archives
```

Sometimes you can try `apt-get autoclean` command.